# How to access containers in host network using docker compose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file that I am trying to build on host network. The build is successful but I am unable to see any result after the build.

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    mycontainer_3000:
        container_name: mycontainer_3000
        build:
            context: src/mycontainer_3000
            dockerfile: ./../../Dockerfile.dev
            args:
                - T_ENV
        image: myproject/mycontainer_3000:latest 
        restart: unless-stopped
        network_mode: host
        volumes:
            - "./src/mycontainer_3000:/usr/src/app"
        depends_on:
            - mycontainer_3001
    mycontainer_3001:
        container_name: mycontainer_3001
        build:
            context: src/mycontainer_3001
            dockerfile: ./../../Dockerfile.dev
            args:
                - T_ENV
        image: myproject/mycontainer_3001:latest
        volumes:
            - "./src/mycontainer_3001:/usr/src/app"
        depends_on:
            - mongo
    mycontainer_3003:
        container_name: mycontainer_3003
        build:
            context: src/mycontainer_3003
            dockerfile: ./../../Dockerfile.dev
            args:
                - T_ENV
        image: myproject/mycontainer_3003:latest
        network_mode: host
        volumes:
            - "./src/mycontainer_3003:/usr/src/app"
        depends_on:
            - mongo
    mycontainer_3002:
        container_name: mycontainer_3002
        build:
            context: src/mycontainer_3002
            dockerfile: ./../../Dockerfile.dev
            args:
                - T_ENV
        image: myproject/mycontainer_3002:latest
        network_mode: host
        volumes:
            - "./src/mycontainer_3002:/usr/src/app"
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        network_mode: host
        volumes:
            - "./db/:/data/db"

    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        restart: always
        network_mode: host
        environment:
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongo:27017/
```

When I compile using `docker-compose up` , all the containers are created successfully.
But when I try to access any of the containers using http://localhost:3000 or any other port, it shows nothing is running on that port!

Comment: You should almost never need host networking, and it doesn't work on non-Linux hosts or if Docker is otherwise running in a VM.  What is your host system?  If your services are listening on single ports, can you use a Compose setup like `ports: ['3000:3000']` instead?

Comment: I am using Docker for Desktop.
The error is this :
`ERROR: for mycontainer_3002  "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings`

Comment: If you're using Docker Desktop, host networking probably doesn't work in the way you expect.  Delete the `network_mode: host` option.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `ports` to explicitly expose them

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
    mycontainer_3000:
        container_name: mycontainer_3000
        build:
            context: src/mycontainer_3000
            dockerfile: ./../../Dockerfile.dev
            args:
                - T_ENV
        image: myproject/mycontainer_3000:latest 
        restart: unless-stopped
        network_mode: host
        #HERE
        ports: '3000:3000'
        volumes:
            - "./src/mycontainer_3000:/usr/src/app"
        depends_on:
            - mycontainer_3001
    mycontainer_3001:
        container_name: mycontainer_3001
        build:
            context: src/mycontainer_3001
            dockerfile: ./../../Dockerfile.dev
            args:
                - T_ENV
        image: myproject/mycontainer_3001:latest
        #HERE
        ports: '3001:3001'
        volumes:
            - "./src/mycontainer_3001:/usr/src/app"
        depends_on:
            - mongo
    mycontainer_3003:
        container_name: mycontainer_3003
        build:
            context: src/mycontainer_3003
            dockerfile: ./../../Dockerfile.dev
            args:
                - T_ENV
        image: myproject/mycontainer_3003:latest
        network_mode: host
        #HERE
        ports: '3003:3003'
        volumes:
            - "./src/mycontainer_3003:/usr/src/app"
        depends_on:
            - mongo
    mycontainer_3002:
        container_name: mycontainer_3002
        build:
            context: src/mycontainer_3002
            dockerfile: ./../../Dockerfile.dev
            args:
                - T_ENV
        image: myproject/mycontainer_3002:latest
        network_mode: host
        #HERE
        ports: '3002:3002'
        volumes:
            - "./src/mycontainer_3002:/usr/src/app"
    mongo:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        network_mode: host
        #HERE
        ports: '27017:27017'
        volumes:
            - "./db/:/data/db"

    mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        restart: always
        network_mode: host
        #HERE
        ports: '8080:8080'
        environment:
            ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://mongo:27017/
```

Comment: Trying this gives an error :
`services.mycontainer_3000.ports contains an invalid type, it should be an array`
And if I provide it in an array : 
`ERROR: for mycontainer_3002  "host" network_mode is incompatible with port_bindings`

Comment: I've updated the YML content, check if it works now. I've changed the port numbers to strings